# PHP Find String and Following Unknown Characters

Tags: php, regex

I'm still learning PHP Regex so I'm hoping someone can help me with what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
$string = 'Writing to tell you that var MyCode = "dentline"; Learn it.';
```

What I'd like to do is match the part of the string which reads

```
var MyCode ="
```

After I match that part, I want to retrieve the rest of the dynamically generated characters that follow that string. In this example, [dentline] is 8 characters, but this may not always be the case. Therefore, I want to match all the way until I reach

```
";
```

After I've effectively captured that part of the string, I want to strip the string so the remaining information is what lies between the double quotes

```
dentline
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Will your string always be double quoted, not single quoted? Could your string contain escaped quotes? Are whitespaces significant in the code? Is the variable name always "MyCode" or can it be other names?

Comment: String is always double quoted. No escaped character, no whitespace, no change in variable name. Just as is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
$string = 'Writing to tell you that var MyCode = "dentline"; Learn it.';
$matches = array();
preg_match('/var MyCode = "(.*?)";/', $string, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

Result:

```
dentline
```

[ideone](http://ideone.com/xCF0P)

**Explanation**

```
var MyCode = "    Match this string literally and exactly
(                 Start a capturing group.
.*?               Match any characters, as few as possible (not greedy)
)                 End the capturing group.
";                Match the closing double quote followed by a semi-colon
```

The capturing group "captures" the contents of the match and stores it in the array `$matches` so that it can be accessed afterwards.

More information about these constructs can be found here:

- [Round Brackets for Grouping and Backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)
- [Watch Out for the Greediness!](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy)

**Variations**

If "MyCode" can vary then use this instead:

```
preg_match('/var \w+ = "(.*?)";/', $string, $matches);
```

In this expression `\w` means "match any word character". You might also want to use `\s+` instead of a space so that you can match one or more of any whitespace characters (also tab and new line). Similarly `\s*` matches zero or more whitespace. So another possibility for you to try is this:

```
preg_match('/var\s+\w+\s*=\s*"(.*?)"\s*;/', $string, $matches);
```

Comment: Amazing, thankyou! Can you give any further information as to how and why this works?

Comment: I couldn't have asked for anything more, truly, a great resource. Thanks!